# How can I see the source code of installed Firefox OS apps?

Tags: source-code

How can I see the files and the source code of installed apps?

For [packaged apps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Marketplace/Options/Packaged_apps) I’d expect to be able to see all files (HTML, CSS, JS, images etc.), for [hosted apps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Marketplace/Options/Hosted_apps) I’d expect to be able to see the manifest, and possibly locally cached files (if the hosted app has offline support).

When I connect my smartphone with a PC (via USB), I can’t find any app files (only user-generated content like photos etc.).

Note that I don’t want to browse the files on an external code repository; I want to see the files that are actually installed on my device.

(A solution for this question would probably also be a solution for the related question [How can I check if an installed Firefox OS app is hosted or packaged?](https://superuser.com/q/798878/151741), but there might be other solutions than checking the source code so they are not duplicates.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable debug mode in order to see the real filesystem. Then you can either:

- import the content with `adb pull /data data` (copies the `/data` directory on your computer);
- or use the shell `adb shell` to get a shell on your phone.

The applications are located in `/data/local/webapps`. You get one directory per application. Packages apps have a `application.zip` file containing all the files -js, css, html).